# Accessing message headers outside handler functions with nservicebus

Tags: asp.net-core, nservicebus

I am using `nservicebus 7` in my `asp.net core 2.1` application.

I wanted to access my custom message headers outside handler functions(specifically in a repository class).

[Saw this answer](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Host/issues/117), but somehow both options are not working for me. Whenever I am trying to access `ContextAccessor.get`, a null references is getting returned.

Any idea what could be wrong or any other way to access `IMessageHandlerContexts` outside handler functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `IUniformSession` might solve your issue.

I was looking on how to inject `IMessageHandlerContext` using a DI container but it seems it was initially a design choice of the NServiceBus team to force us to pass this object around.

Then they must have added the uniform session feature.

I haven't used it myself (yet) but I'm starting to believe that's the way to go.

For reference:

- https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/uniformsession
- https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Host/issues/117

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would try to capture the information required from the headers using a pipeline behavior. The information can be stored in a type defined by yourself, which can be registered in the container and then injected into the repository. That way, you don't need to pass on the IMessageHandlerContext to the repository.

A colleague of mine has a sample for this:
https://github.com/ramonsmits/NServiceBus.InjectStorageContext/tree/v7

Answer (score -1):

`IMessageHandlerContext` is only available inside a handler.  However, you can pass it as a parameter to other parts of your code.

For example,

```
public async Task Handle(MyCommand message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
{
     var result = await SomeOtherFunction(message, context).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

You could also read the headers in the handler and pass just those to your repository method.  See [Manipulating message headers](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/header-manipulation#reading-incoming-headers-from-a-handler).  Relevant part below.

```
public class ReadHandler :
    IHandleMessages<MyMessage>
{
    public Task Handle(MyMessage message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        var headers = context.MessageHeaders;
        var nsbVersion = headers[Headers.NServiceBusVersion];
        var customHeader = headers["MyCustomHeader"];
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: My question was specifically on how to get DI support for IMessageHandlerContext outside handlers/saga handlers

Comment: @Sajan Can you please elaborate on your use case?  IMessageHandlerContext does not make sense to use outside message handlers.

See https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgrades/5to6/moving-away-from-ibus#dependency-injection.  Although it's for the version 5 to 6 conversion, the concept from 6 would apply to version 7 as well.

Are you trying to read messages from the queue directly, i.e. not via a NSB handler?  If so, I would advise against manipulating the queue transport directly.

Comment: Hi Scott, I was trying to create an nservice bus version of https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/tree/dev/src/Services/Ordering. I wanted to publish integration events from the domain event handlers. The only option is to use IMessageSession, but doing so does not propagate my custom headers and conversation id is also getting distracted even though everything under one logical transaction

Comment: @ScottHoffman - Sorry for downvoting. Your answer is very useful!